# Target JDK in PMD

Tags: java, pmd

We are using PMD 4.2.5 and below is the error we see

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 318214, Size: 22665
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.MatchAlgorithm.tokenAt(MatchAlgorithm.java:50)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.MatchAlgorithm.hash(MatchAlgorithm.java:96)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.MatchAlgorithm.findMatches(MatchAlgorithm.java:59)
```

We have changed the `maxinimIndexcount` to 100 from 50. Even now we see the error yet time.

Would moving to PMD 5 solve the issues? There is no mention of it in their bug fixes.

We also use

```
<pmd id="pmdTask" rulesetfiles="${rulesets}" encoding="UTF-8" targetjdk="${targetjdk}">
```

What is targetjdk replaced with in PMD 5?